# Issue in generating the chart with required color, i.e. specified colors are not displayed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular

[image]I am facing some issues in loading the bubble chart with specified/required colors. I tried the POC and it works fine, but when the chart is loaded with the actual application the color is changed i.e. some other bootstrap css class is overriding the specified and the bubbles/circles are rendered in black color. I am using the following bootstrap references in the index.html.

```
 <!-- Bootstrap and JQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you notice the POC in the plunker the circles are generated with white color and that is the required one, but if you notice the snapshot it is changed/displayed in black color. how do i override and make it working?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NYTtNZ2c0tYD2yHaMgRR?p=preview)

The code for angular2 component which generates the bubble chart can be refered in the plunker specified link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option mentioned by @Yakov Fain would work, but using ViewEncapsulation.None has other side effects, so read up on those if you want to go that route.

This question has come up [before](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7769) with Angular 2 and d3.
You can use shadow piercing style selectors e.g.

```
:host /deep/ h3 {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

> We can use the /deep/ selector to force a style down through the child
>   component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ selector
>   works to any depth of nested components, and it applies both to the
>   view children and the content children of the component.
>   The /deep/ selector also has the alias >>>. We can use either of the
>   two interchangeably.

Read more about these special selectors here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors

Answer (score 1):

By default, Angular 2 emulates Shadow Dom (  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.Emulated) so the styles of your component don't leak out to the DOM.  Turn it off by adding this line to the template of your component:
`encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None`